# URL routing and permanent page redirection for old page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, http-status-code-301

suppose our company has website which was developed by asp.net web form v1.1. it is running for last 5 year. people search google by keyword and got the link to come to our site...it means google cached all the pages of our site. now our company planing to develop our site with asp.net 4.0 and our company CTO want to use asp.net 4.0 routing feature for search engine friendly. i am aware of how to use url routing feature....here is small sample snippet of url routing.

[image]

for our new website pages name will be change. so when some one will search google  and get link and when click on those link then request will come to our site but page not found will show because page name will be changed. so how to write the logic in such a way as a result when old request will come then routing will redirect to right page and also do the permanent redirection for google as a result from the next time user will get right page url. so my concern is how to write the logic which will drive the user to right page if the old page does not exist, the user will be redirected to right page using routing. please help me with code & concept. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a HTTP 301 Permanent Redirection

Using .NET Framework v4:

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("NewPage.aspx");
```

EDIT:
I jumped in too quickly there... a good MVC solution would be: http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/04/25/ASPNET-MVC-Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx

This will redirect the request to the right place and return a 301 back...

Comment: i guess u guys do not understand my requirement. i need logic by which i can determine that requested page is old page name and now it has been changed along with folder structure. so when page is old page and not available now then it should be redirected to right page by routing. i hope i am clear what i want?

Comment: Perhaps. But perhaps you don't understand the answers you are receiving. When an page URL changes, you have two main objectives - to get send the request to the right place, and to let the requester know that the page has been permanently moved (a HTTP 301 Permanent Redirection). Without the 301, Google (and other referrers) will continue to send traffic to the wrong place - with a 301, they know to send traffic to the new location. You can do this via routing or you can handle it earlier in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it via MVC, you will always have to manage those old routes. I think the best way is tu use directly IIS for this scenario. The url module in IIS allows you to configure permanent redirects very easily.

Comment: i guess u guys do not understand my requirement. i need logic by which i can determine that requested page is old page name and now it has been changed along with folder structure. so when page is old page and not available now then it should be redirected to right page by routing. i hope i am clear what i want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert of MVC, infact a starter, so the solution that comes in my mind is you will have to register all routes for your existing pages like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "BooksCategory", // Route name
            "products/books.aspx", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Products", action = "Browse", category = "Books" }
        );
```

You can enhance it according to your needs.

Comment: i guess u guys do not understand my requirement. i need logic by which i can determine that requested page is old page name and now it has been changed along with folder structure. so when page is old page and not available now then it should be redirected to right page by routing. i hope i am clear what i want?

Answer (score 0):

I's suggest using a hybrid of this tools. You should return 301 as it's a permanent move. Google should pick-up on that when it starts scanning your new site.

I'd suggest you also need to keep your legacy urls separate, so they don't interfere with the current site. At some point in the future, perhaps when this new site becomes the legacy site, you'll want to organise your urls. By knowing what's needed by the app & what's for SEO might help.

You can probably do your SEO redirection using IIS and it's redirection module. Also, have look at Googles (and Bings) webmaster tools. They should help you figure our what the search engine is seeing on your site.

Comment: i guess u guys do not understand my requirement. i need logic by which i can determine that requested page is old page name and now it has been changed along with folder structure. so when page is old page and not available now then it should be redirected to right page by routing. i hope i am clear what i want?